# How to parse a string array with Mustache Template Lambda in java

Tags: java, mustache, spring-restdocs

I am currently working on implementing a Mustache Lambda to parse this object:
[{name=Content-Type, value=application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8}, {name=Content-Length, value=906}]

My template lambda looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Mustache.Lambda;
import org.springframework.restdocs.mustache.Template.Fragment;


public class GetContentType implements Lambda {
  @Override
  public void execute(Fragment fragment, Writer writer) throws IOException {
    fragment.execute(writer);
  }
}
```

The mustache template looks like this

```
{{#getContentType}}
     {{http-response.headers}}
{{/getContentType}}
```

The output from generating the template produces the following

```
[{name=Content-Type, value=application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8}, {name=Content-Length, value=906}]
```

I am trying to figure out how to return the value `application/hal+json` from the key `Content-Type` in the java function. There isn't much documentation on this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `Fragment` that is passed into your `Lambda` has a context that's available via the `context()` method. The exact type and content of the context depends on how your lambda's being used so it's typed as an `Object`.

It looks like you're working with the `headers` that are added to the context by Spring REST Docs. In this case the headers are a `List` of `Map`, where each map contains `name` and `value` entries.

Hopefully this gives you enough to retrieve the `context()` from the `Fragment` and start casting it and drilling down into its content to find the map with a `name=Content-Type` entry from where you can retrieve the entry that's keyed with `value`.